# Why is there number 3 at Java input dialog?

Tags: java, joptionpane

```
String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Question", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
```

This always gives me an input dialog with a text input field that always shows up with the number 3 written in the input  field. Why is that?

Comment: `JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE == 3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling [`showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, Object initialSelectionValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)), and you are passing `QUESTION_MESSAGE` (i.e. the number 3) as the `initialSelectionValue`.

You could instead call [`showInputDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)), which has a `messageType` parameter, which would accept `QUESTION_MESSAGE`.

That would mean changing your code to say:

```
showInputDialog(null, "Question", "Title", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)
```

And try looking at the API to figure out what method you are actually trying to call.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your code there might be a misplaced '3' around because JOptionPane class displays exactly what it recieve.

Why don't you share more of your code or maybe try to debug your code using your preffered IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse...)